# How can a horse take the Mare lifepath?

Tags: character-creation, mount, burning-wheel

In the [Mount Burner](https://www.burningwheel.com/wiki/index.php?title=Downloads#The_Mount_Burner), horses can be burned by taking lifepaths. Leads are to lifepaths, not settings. I can't find any lead to the Mare lifepath. Does a lead exist (that I have simply missed), or is there some other means of taking the Mare lifepath?

Answer (score 4):

After searching the pdf, it appears to be an oversight that Mare does not have a lead.

Comment: It also seems weird that there's only one lead to Stud.

Comment: And the only to be wild is to be born a turcoman and directly go to wild. Even feral can't go to wild, anymore.